# How to compare values of consecutive elements in a vector for filtering?

Tags: clojure

I need to filter a given vector such that the output contains only those elements that are not a duplicate of an immediate neighbor.

```
Example : I/P -> [1 1 3 2 2 4 5 5]
          O/P -> [3 4]
```

Comment: What should be the output for `[1 1 3 2 2 4 5 5 2 5 5]` ?  (Is the last `2` discarded because there was a repeating `2` earlier in the sequence? Or is it kept for not having another `2` as a neighbor?)

Comment: The output should be  [3 4 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly the same logic as @amalloy's answer, but it uses `transducers` instead of the threading macro (`->>`).

```
(defn isolate [coll]
  (transduce
   (comp
   (partition-by identity)
   (remove next)
   (map first))
  conj coll))
```

It should be more efficient, at least on large collections.

The `partition-by identity` partitions coll to sub-lists of identical elements. The `remove next` drops all sub-lists whose `next` is not nil (i.e., they have more than one element). The last `map first` takes the first element of each sub-list, thus flattening the list of lists to a list of elements.

Just run each of the steps separately to see how it works.

Answer (score 8):

```
(defn isolated [coll]
  (->> coll
       (partition-by identity)
       (remove next)
       (map first)))
```

Comment: Nah. It's pretty self-explanatory, and the functions used are easy to look up. If Stack Overflow doesn't want answers like this, they are welcome to delete it.

Comment: or `flatten` instead of `(map first)`

Comment: @fl00r No, that would be quite wrong. Try it with an input of `[[1 2] [1 2]]`.

Comment: @amalloy, but `(remove next)` already removed all non-single seqs, didn't it?

Comment: @fl00r Yes, we have a list of singleton lists. However, the item within that singleton list might *itself* be a list, which you shouldn't flatten. My sample input was wrong, though: it should have no duplicates. `(partition-by identity [[1 2]])`, for example, yields `(([1 2]))`. `remove next` doesn't change it, but then the result we want is `([1 2])` (i.e., the input unchanged). `map first` yields that, but using `flatten` instead would yield `(1 2)`, an overzealous flattening.

Answer (score 4):

Using transducers like @amitr's solution, but IMHO, a little cleaner:

```
(def isolate
  (comp
   (partition-by identity)
   (remove next)
   cat))
```

It can then be used with `sequence`, `into`, whichever transducer-accepting function you desire.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a brute force solution so hopefully we'll see some more satisfying answers, but to get the ball rolling ...

```
(defn lonely? 
  "Return the ith element of v if it doesn't have a matching neighbor"
  [i v]
  (when (cond
          (zero? i) (not= (v 0) (v 1))
          (= i (- (count v) 1)) (not= (v i) (v (- i 1)))
          :else (and (not= (v i) (v (- i 1)))
                     (not= (v i) (v (+ i 1)))))
    (v i)))

> (def v [1 1 3 2 2 4 5 5])

> (keep #(lonely? % v) (range (count v)))
(3 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(def data-1 [1 1 3 2 2 4 5 5])

(def data-2 [1 1 3 2 2 4 5 5 2 5 5])

(defn reducer [[v p] n]
  (cond
    (empty? v) [[n] n]
    (= (peek v) n) [(pop v) n]
    (= n p) [v n]
    :else [(conj v n) n]))

(first (reduce reducer [[] nil] data-1))
;[3 4]

(first (reduce reducer [[] nil] data-2))
;[3 4 2]
```

Note that this solution also covers cases where there are more than 2 adjacent values that are the same such as:

```
(def data-3 [1 1 3 2 2 2 4 5 5 2 5 5])
;[3 4 2]
```

All the hard work goes on in the function reducer.

Mentally I always tag the first parameter of `reduce` as "the accumulator" and the second as "the new value".

In this case, the accumulator has to have two parts: the vector that you are creating and the last number seen. (Note that if you only expect duplicates to occur as pairs, the last number seen is not necessary.)

So the `[v p]` is "the accumulator" part of the reducer - `v` is the vector you are creating and `p` is the previous value seen. The `n` parameter is "the new value".

The explanation of the 4 conditions is:

1. If `v` is empty, just make a new vector with the new value and record
   the new value. This is necessary because peek on an empty vector
   (the next condition) will result in an exception.
2. If the last value of `v` is the same as the new value, remove it and record 
   the new value.
3. If the new value (`n`) is the same as the last value (`p`) ignore
   it. This condition enables us to eliminate values that are repeated
   several times.
4. If none of these conditions are true it's ok to append the value :)

Answer (score 1):

Building it more or less from the ground up, you can get destructuring to do much of the work:

```
(defn no-dupes [coll]
  (when-let [[x & [y & ys :as xs]] (seq coll)]
    (if xs
      (if (= x y)
        (recur (drop-while #(= x %) ys))
        (lazy-seq (cons x (no-dupes xs))))
      (list x))))
```

Having said that, I made two errors in these few lines, whereas [Alan Malloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54700870/1562315) is transparently correct.

---

Is this is any faster than [@dpassen's neat transducer version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713040/1562315)?

Yes. It's about three times as fast: about 500 nano seconds compared to about 1.5 micro seconds for the short example, according to  Criterium.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this :

```
(defn remove-consecutive-duplicates [inp]
    (let [intm (into [] (partition-by identity inp))]
             (reduce (fn [acc n]
                (if (= 1 (count n))
                  (conj acc n)
                  acc ))
              [] intm)))
```

Do note that dedupe does not give the desired output.

Comment: `dedupe`, not `dudupe`?